# why replace Replace ~ with ~T to avoid md5 hashes in markdown parsing?

Tags: javascript, markdown

I am reading the [Markdown.Converter.js](https://github.com/ujifgc/pagedown/blob/master/Markdown.Converter.js) to understand how the markdown parse works.

On line 258 it says:

```
        // attacklab: Replace ~ with ~T
        // This lets us use tilde as an escape char to avoid md5 hashes
        // The choice of character is arbitray; anything that isn't
        // magic in Markdown will work.
        text = text.replace(/~/g, "~T");
```

on line 297:

```
        // attacklab: Restore tildes
        text = text.replace(/~T/g, "~");
```

The annotation is very well written, but I still failed to understand it. Why "avoid md5 hashes"? 
Can you help explain it in detail, perhaps with an example?

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea why they mention "md5 hashes". But it's quite clear that they need to escape tilde characters before using the tilde for escape sequences (`~E`, `~D`, `~0` etc)

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly the point I am not clear.

Comment: I'm no parser-expert, but this implementation seems very hacky, relying on regexes like Gruber's perl version. Maybe take a look at a (possible cleaner) js-markdown-parser implementation as well? https://github.com/jgm/CommonMark/blob/master/js/lib/blocks.js

Answer (score 2):

It's a reference to the [original perl code](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), which did its escapes in an, err, strange way:

```
(line 497)
# Within tags, encode * and _ so they don't conflict
# with their use in Markdown for italics and strong.
# We're replacing each such character with its
# corresponding MD5 checksum value; this is likely
# overkill, but it should prevent us from colliding
# with the escape values by accident.
```

The people from attacklab did not want to recreate this hack (probably because there's no native md5 function) in JS, so they did *avoid md5 hashes* and used tilde characters for escape sequences instead.

Comment: The link is to Daring page, not perl code. How the commented text that you provided explain the ~ to ~T replacement?

Comment: I mean the perl code from the zip file that you can download there (I didn't find a web preview anywhere). It does not explain the use of tilde characters, as the original code doesn't do this. That is explained in the attacklab comment: "*This lets us use tilde as an escape char*"